# In react hooks, how can i pass the filtered values to the chart?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, chart.js

I am using React with hooks to pass filtered values to a chart.
The problem is that i was no able to pass the "filterData" values to the chart:

```
const filterData = data.datasets[0].data.filter(value => value > Number(filterdatanumber))
```

Any suggestion on how can i solve this?
I have tried different solutions existing in these videos https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cz2rG-OVXXU, or create a new variable, among others, however nothing worked.

The complete code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';

export default function VerticalBar() {
  const [firstNumber, setFirstNumber] = useState("");
    const textChangeHandler = (i) => {
    setFirstNumber(i.target.value);
    console.log("target.value", i.target.value);
    filterChart(Number(i.target.value)); 
  };

    const data = {
      labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Weekly Sales',
        data: [18, 12, 6, 9, 11, 3, 9],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
          'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
          'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    };
    
    const filterChart = (filterdatanumber = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER) => {
      const filterData = data.datasets[0].data.filter(value => value > Number(filterdatanumber))
      // const filterData = data.datasets[0].data.filter(value => value > 9)

      const filterLabels = [];
      const filterColors = [];
      let i = 0;
      for (i; i < filterData.length; i++) {
        const result = data.datasets[0].data.indexOf(filterData[i]);
        const labelsResult = data.labels[result];
        const colorssResult = data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[result];
        filterLabels.push(labelsResult );
        filterColors.push(colorssResult);
    }
    
    console.log("filterData", filterData)
    console.log("filterLabels", filterLabels)
    console.log("filterColors",filterColors)

    data.datasets[0].data = filterData;
    data.labels = filterLabels;
    data.datasets[0].backgroundColor = filterColors;
  }
  filterChart();

    return (
      <div >
       <Bar  data={data} />
       <input value={firstNumber} type="number" name="firstNumber" onChange={textChangeHandler} />
      </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: actually your code is applying the filtered data already. how do you see it is not?

Comment: The new approach to solve this problem below is much better, however the bars in the chart lost the correct indexing therefore some of them display randomly. Do you have any suggestion to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your code has many problems regarding how you handle state date inside the component.

If `data` is constant then you can move it outside the component.

The function `filterData` can be replaced with a state holding the filtered data and a `useEffect` that will be triggered when another `filterdatanumber` state changes.

Here is an example code with these changes.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";

const data = {
  labels: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Weekly Sales",
      data: [18, 12, 6, 9, 11, 3, 9],
      backgroundColor: [
        "rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)",
        "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
        "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)",
        "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
        "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)",
        "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)",
        "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)",
      ],
      borderColor: [
        "rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)",
        "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
        "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)",
        "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
        "rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)",
        "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)",
        "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
      ],
      borderWidth: 1,
    },
  ],
};

export default function VerticalBar() {
  const [firstNumber, setFirstNumber] = useState("");
  const [filterdatanumber, setFilterdatanumber] = useState(
    Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER
  );
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState(data);
  const textChangeHandler = (i) => {
    setFirstNumber(i.target.value);
    console.log("target.value", i.target.value);
    filterChart(Number(i.target.value));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const newData = { ...data };
    const filteredData = [];
    const filterLabels = [];
    const filterColors = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < newData.datasets[0].data.length; i++) {
      const value = newData.datasets[0].data[i]
      if (value > Number(filterdatanumber)) {
        const labelsResult = newData.labels[i];
        const colorssResult = newData.datasets[0].backgroundColor[i];
        filterLabels.push(labelsResult);
        filterColors.push(colorssResult);
        filteredData.push(value)
      }
    }
    console.log("filteredData", filteredData);
    console.log("filterLabels", filterLabels);
    console.log("filterColors", filterColors);
    newData.datasets[0].data = filteredData;
    newData.labels = filterLabels;
    newData.datasets[0].backgroundColor = filterColors;
    setFilteredData(newData);
  }, [filterdatanumber]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Bar data={filteredData} />
      <input
        value={firstNumber}
        type="number"
        name="firstNumber"
        onChange={textChangeHandler}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Please remember that this code is just an example, maybe it will need some edits in order to match your needs.

Comment: this is a much better approach however the correct indexing is not working anymore, and that has been my main problem during the last weeks. Can you please help?

Comment: What do you mean with "correct indexing"?

Comment: The bars in the chart lost the correct indexing therefore some of them display randomly.

Comment: The console.logs print them correctly, however the chart displays the bar values incorrectly.

Comment: Please provide a working example on codesandbox or similar.

Comment: Yes, here it is https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-shape-hxmsc?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I updated the answer. There was a bug in how you calculate the labels and colors inside the for loop. If now the answer is correct please consider to mark it as accepted in order to help others to find the right solution quickly.

Comment: I have tried this updated answer with the number 9 for example and it shows also bars with values below 9 in the chart therefore there still may be something to be adjusted in the code. Any ideas?

Comment: @David I updated the answer, I think that any further bug fixing is out of scope of the question so please try to go ahead on you our own and I also invite you, if the answer is correct, to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final solution fully working and with a refactored 3rd approach. The values are matching the keys consistently when filtered and displayed correctly in the chart.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback, useMemo } from "react";
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";

export default function VerticalBar() {
  const [data, setData] = useState ([
    {val: 18, label: "Mon"},
    {val: 1, label: "Tue"},
    {val: 5, label: "Wed"}, 
    {val: 8, label: "Thu"}, 
    {val: 19, label: "Fri"}, 
    {val: 5, label: "Sat"}, 
    {val: 7, label: "Sun"}
  ])

  const chartConfig = useMemo(() => {
    return  {
        labels: data.map(el => el.label), 
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Weekly Sales",
            data: data.map(el => el.val),
            backgroundColor: [
              "rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)",
              "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
              "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)",
              "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
              "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)",
              "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)",
              "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)",
            ],
            borderColor: [
              "rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)",
              "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
              "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)",
              "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
              "rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)",
              "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)",
              "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
            ],
            borderWidth: 1,
          },
        ],
      };
    
  }, [data])

  const textChangeHandler = useCallback(
    (event) => {
    setData(prevData => {
      return prevData.filter((el) => parseInt(event.target.value, 10) < el.val)
    })
  }, [setData]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Bar data={chartConfig} />
      <input
        type="number"
        name="firstNumber"
        onChange={textChangeHandler}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```